# Error installing matplotlib in a virtual environment python 2.7

Tags: matplotlib, pip, virtualenv

I have been trying to install matplotlib in a virtual environment using pip.

after working on the virtual environment I tried:

```
$pip install matplotlib
```

but I get the error:

```
unable to execute 'c++' : No such file or directory
error : command 'c++' failed with exit status 1
------------------------------------------
Cleaning up
```

I am on ubuntu 14.04 and matplotlib works well for me when not using  virtualenv, but I would like to have it in a virtualenv for separate projects that I have.

any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try to install gcc with apt-get?

Comment: yes thats why I have it working in my global site-packages, I just can not get it to install in virtualenv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this problem by just upgrading pip, it seems there was an issue of version 1.5.4 which was installed when creating virtualenv.

```
$ pip install --upgrade pip
```

then installed matplotlib using pip

```
$pip install matplotlib
```